# Dynamically added objects and work with them

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox

my code dynamically adding ListBoxes, which contains buttons. Buttons dynamically addind another buttons. Well... thats expectation. My code doesn't works.

Here is my code:

```
public Button createElements(string nameOfElement)
    {
        if (nameOfElement.Contains("Floor"))
        {
            // code creating Button
            return floorButton;
        }
        else if (nameOfElement.Contains("Sound"))
        {
            // code creating Button
            return soundButton;
        }
        else if (nameOfElement.Contains("Add"))
        {
            // code creating Button
            return addButton;
        }
        return null;
    }

private ListBox addNewListBox(ListBox targetElement, int ex)
    {
        // vytvori ListBox do hlavniho ListBoxu
        ListBox elementListBox = new ListBox();

        elementListBox.Name = "elementListBox" + indexY;
        elementListBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        elementListBox.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse("<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>");

        if (ex == 1) 
        {
            targetElement.Items.Remove(addFloor);
            targetElement.Items.Add(elementListBox);
            elementListBox.Items.Add(createElements("Floor"));
            elementListBox.Items.Add(createElements("Sound"));
            elementListBox.Items.Add(createElements("Add"));
            targetElement.Items.Add(addFloor);
            indexY++;
            indexX = 0;
        }
        return elementListBox;
    }
```

Here is detail of final function.

```
private void putElements(ListBox targetElement, Button targetObject)
    {
        targetElement.Items.Add(targetObject);
        // there's problem
        MessageBox.Show("targetElement: ", targetElement.Name);
        MessageBox.Show("targetObject", targetObject.Name);
    }
```

Click event calling this function:

```
putElements(addNewListBox(mainListBox, 0), createElements("Sound"));
```

MessageBoxes prints names of objects in last function. Objects are right, but this line:

```
targetElement.Items.Add(targetObject);
```

there is problem - this line doing nothing..

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

You're just adding the new ListBox to your `mainListBox` if the ex-value is 1, but in your case it's 0.

So your new ListBox (`targetElement` in `putElements`-method) will never be added to your `mainListBox` and hence not displayed. Thats why `targetElement.Items.Add(targetObject);` seems to not work.

Comment: OK, so how can i get the existing ListBox?

You know, thats problem, when u need ListBox with index 3, but that List box is dynamically added.

I need adding buttons (dynamically adding buttons) to dynamically added ListBox.

Comment: Which existing ListBox do you mean? If you want to get a particular dynamically added ListBox, you could give them unique names (f.e. with a counter) and than iterate through the mainListBox' Items to find a matching name.